# What does "intervening" mean in this sentence?

Tags: word-meaning, american-english

I can get most of this sentence, but this word is confusing me a bit as it doesn't seem to be used in the usual way that I've seen.

> Catastrophic floods do far more damage and move more material than all of the **intervening** floods put together.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, intervening is used to indicate that non-catastrophic floods that occur between catastrophic floods do less damage and move less material. Intervene is often used to refer to something coming between two things in space, but in this case its referring to something (or things) coming between two things in **time**.

Comment: Ah I see, I can see why I was confused there though. Thanks for clarifying it!